# How do I create a TypeScript project with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to create a typescript project.

Very simply I want my ts files to turn into js files when I build.

I'm using VisualStudio 2015 Enterprise.

I created a Blank WebApplication.

I tried to install Typescript but it says typescript 1.6.3 has already been preinstalled.

When I create a ts file nothing happens.

When I right-click the project I do not have a Typescript tab in Project properties.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This should just work out of the box. What do the icons of the ts files look like? If you look at the properties of a ts file what do you see?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you create a TypeScript web project instead of a blank web project in the new project dialog:

[image]

When you build the project, VS will compile your ts files into js files. But you won't see them unless you turn on 'show all files' in the solution explorer:

[image]

That should be all you have to do. You can configure advanced properties of the build by right clicking on the project file and selecting project properties:

[image]

Hope that's enough to get you started.